# AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__' in python and kivy code

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

Hello while using kivy i encountered this error. My purpose is to create a login screen of my app which will check whether the data entered by user is correct or not. But while doing so i am getting this error again and again.

---

My code is given below:

> Python file:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp  
import mysql.connector as ms
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


acc = NumericProperty("")
pw = StringProperty("")

class safarApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'BlueGray'
        return
        
    def Login(self):
            self.acc = self.root.ids.acc_num.text
            
            self.pw = self.root.ids.password.text
            
            host = ms.connect(
              host="localhost",
              user="root",
              password="bhawarth20",
              database="safar"
              )
              
            cur = host.cursor(buffered = True)
            
            
            
            cur.execute("Select * from data where Account_Number = %s and Password = %s collate utf8mb4_bin", (self.acc, self.pw))
            data="error" #initially just assign the value
            
            for i in cur:
                data=i #if cursor has no data then loop will not run and value of data will be 'error'
                if data== "error":
                    print("User Does not exist")
                else:
                    print("User exist")

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass
    
    
class SignUpScreen(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(LoginScreen(name= "login"))
sm.add_widget(SignUpScreen(name= "signup"))



                    
                    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    safarApp().run()
```

> KV file:

```
ScreenManager:
    LoginScreen:
    SignUpScreen:


<LoginScreen>:
    name: 'login'
    MDCard:
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 300,400
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        elevation:10
        spacing: 25
        padding: 25
        orientation: 'vertical'
        
        MDLabel:
            text: "Safar Login"
            font_size: 40
            halign: 'center'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.texture_size[1]
            padding_y: 10
            pos_hint: {'center_y': 1}

        MDTextField:
            id: acc_num
            hint_text: 'Account Number'
            icon_right: 'account'
            max_text_length: 6
            size_hint_x: None
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
            width: 200
            font_size: 18
            required: True
                        
        MDTextField:
            id: password
            hint_text: 'Password'
            password: True
            size_hint_x: None
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
            width: 200
            font_size: 18
            icon_right: 'eye'
            required: True
            
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            id: Login
            text: 'Login'
            size_hint_x: None
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
            width: 200
            elevation: 10
            on_release: app.Login()

            
        MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            id: Sign_Up
            text: 'Sign Up'
            size_hint_x: None
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
            width: 200
            elevation: 10
            on_release: root.manager.current = 'signup'
            
                
<SignUpScreen>:
    name: 'signup'
    MDLabel:
        text: "Hello World!!!"
```

> This is the error i am getting:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Welcome\.kivy\logs\kivy_21-07-12_51.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init
py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 186 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [KivyMD      ] 0.104.2, git-bc7d1f5, 2021-06-06 (installed at "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3
2\lib\site-packages\kivymd\__init__.py")
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Activate GLES2/ANGLE context
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <angle_sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 2.0.0 (ANGLE 2.1.13739 git hash: 385fb40fd460)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Google Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'ANGLE (Mobile Intel(R) 965 Express Chipset Family Direct3D11 vs_4_0 ps_4_0)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.00 (ANGLE 2.1.13739 git hash: 385fb40fd460)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 861, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'acc_num'

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\my projects of python\Safar\safar.py", line 69, in <module>
     safarApp().run()
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 950, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 582, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.mainloop()
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 347, in mainloop
     self.idle()
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 391, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 342, in dispatch_inpu
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 308, in post_dispatch
put
     wid.dispatch('on_touch_up', me)
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 709, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\behaviors\ripple_behavior.py",
ne 296, in on_touch_up
     return super().on_touch_up(touch)
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\button.py", line 981, in on_to
_up
     return super().on_touch_up(touch)
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 179,
on_touch_up
     self.dispatch('on_release')
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 705, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1248, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch
   File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 1132, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch
   File "C:\Users\Welcome\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 57, in custom
llback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "D:\my projects of python\Safar\safar.kv", line 56, in <module>
     on_release: app.Login()
   File "D:\my projects of python\Safar\safar.py", line 27, in Login
     self.acc = self.root.ids.acc_num.text
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

**Please help me to get this error solved soon. Any help would be greatly aprreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
    self.acc = self.root.ids.acc_num.text
    self.pw = self.root.ids.password.text
```

is trying to access `ids` that are not in the `root` `ids` dictionary. Those `ids` are defined in the `<LoginScreen>:` rule, so they appear in the `LoginScreen` instance. Replace those two line with:

```
    login_screen = self.root.get_screen('login')
    self.acc = login_screen.ids.acc_num.text
    self.pw = login_screen.ids.password.text
```